# Add Category Id As a Class Name For A Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

So I have a custom post type on my website "Case Studies" and each post can have 1-3 categories ("Web-design", "SEO", "Facebook-Ads") depending of which I checked off in my wordpress dashboard..

Here is the code I currently have

```
<div class="container">
<div class="category_container">
    <p class="category_item" id="all">All</p>
    <p class="category_item" id="website">Websites</p>
    <p class="category_item" id="facebook">Facebook Ads</p>
    <p class="category_item" id="seo">SEO</p>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex">
        <?php

           $args1 = array( 'post_type' => array('case_studies'), 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'orderby' => 'date' );
           $loop = new WP_Query( $args1 );

           while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { 

           $loop->the_post();

           $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID));


        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
             <div class="case-study-content">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="blog_blocks">
                        <div class="b_image">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="b_h_sec">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?></p>
                        <span class="r_m">Read More</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
             </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the wordpress loop to automatically add the class name of each category for the individual post after "col-sm-4".

For example, if the post has a category of "website" and "facebook" checked in the wordpress dashboard, I want the post have a class of

```
<div class="col-sm-4 website facebook">

</div>
```

The category id of facebook is 7, category id of website is 5 and category id of seo is 6.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

As I underastand you want to show the taxonomy term slug as a class. So you have to get all taxonomy terms for this post. For Example :

```
 <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'your_taxonomy_name' ); ?>
 <div class="col-sm-4 <?php if ( $terms != null ){ foreach( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->slug; } } ?> ">
       <div class="case-study-content">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="blog_blocks">
                    <div class="b_image">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b_h_sec">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?></p>
                    <span class="r_m">Read More</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I get an error saying
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/home1/lionbus1/public_html/wp-content/themes/lmb_theme/template-casestudies.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />